# how do I write a function to form a string from array?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some quiz here and I'm wondering how do I write a function to form a string: `HEY JUDE`?

I have the initial array which looks like this `[ 'H', 'E', 'Y', '', '', 'J', 'U', 'D', 'E' ]`

I understand this is a simple quiz but I don't know how do I leave only one space instead of 2 between the words.

Comment: There is one function already written `arr.join('')`.

Comment: If these are spaces `'', '',`, then `array.join('')` will do. If not, you can try `array.reduce((p, c) => p + (c || ' '))`

Comment: this gives me 2 spaces between HEY and JUDE

Comment: @karolis2017 `arr.join(''').replace(/\s+/g, ' ')`.

Comment: as above with `.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')`

Comment: @Rajesh - `.reduce((p, c) => p + ((!!c || (p.substr(-1) !== ' ')) ? c || ' ' : ''), '');` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have posted an answer using `for` since join and reduce is making things complicated. Hope it helps in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many ways but the simplest way would be to use a `for` loop.

#### Logic

- Create a temp variable that will hold last appended character.
- Loop over array and set this variable.

  - If current char is blank,

    - And if last char is not space, set it as space.
    - If is is space, keep it as it is.
  - Else, set value as current char
- Not append this char to your string.

```js
var data = [ 'H', 'E', 'Y', '', '', 'J', 'U', 'D', 'E' ];

var str = '';
var lastChar = null;

for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
  if(!data[i] && lastChar !== ' '){
    lastChar = ' ';
  }
  else {
    lastChar = data[i];
  }
  str += lastChar;
}

console.log(str)
```

Comment: I know the question is very basic, but people(*including me*) have suggested different ways using `array.reduce`, `array.join` and `regex`. This has made things a little complicated. So thought of answering with the simplest approach I could. If you think, anything in above answer is inappropriate/ incorrect, please feel free to **comment** along with your vote. That would help everyone.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment. Cross my heart won't do revenge vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the array with space and delete a single space or multiple spaces.

```js
var array = ['H', 'E', 'Y', '', '', 'J', 'U', 'D', 'E'];

console.log(array.join(' ').replace(/ (?=  |\S)/g, ''));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use join property of array.

[Reference for array join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

**var arr = [ 'H', 'E', 'Y', '', '', 'J', 'U', 'D', 'E' ] then 
arr.join('') will give you "HEYJUDE"**

If you add one whitespace in between

**var arr = [ 'H', 'E', 'Y', ' ', 'J', 'U', 'D', 'E' ] then 
arr.join('') will give you "HEY JUDE"**

Comment: so, change the input to get the output you require? what if you can't change the input?

Comment: Then for that scenario regex will come into picture

Comment: as has been posted in the comments on the question :p

Comment: You should always assume input cannot change and provide solution for it. If you think changing input would make things easy, you can add a caveat with sample. But do not assume, its ok to change the input

Comment: `regex will come into picture` - not necessarily :p